# pandoc: How to link to a section in another markdown file?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I would like to create two markdown files with links between their sections. The challenge here it's that I want the files to work correctly whether I ask pandic to concatenate them to a single HTML file, or to separate HTML files. The trouble is that in the latter case the link needs to know there name of the other HTML file in order to work properly.

It's there some way for pandoc to manage this without creating distinct versions of the markdown input?

Answer (score 7):

The following uses [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to fix your links.  It assumes that links are written by prefixing them with the file in which the link is defined, for example `[see here](some-other-file.md#topic)`.  Some editors make it simple to switch to the respective file, so this can be an additional advantage.

When converting to multiple HTML files, all we need to do is replace the `.md` file extension in these links with `.html`.

```
-- fix-links-multiple-files.lua
function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('(.+)%.md%#(.+)', '%1.html#%2')
  return link
end
```

Run it with

```
pandoc --lua-filter fix-links-multiple-files.lua file-1.md -o file-1.html
```

In the case of a single file, we can just drop the file part of the link:

```
-- fix-links-single-file.lua
function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('.+%.md%#(.+)', '#%1')
  return link
end
```

Run with

```
pandoc --lua-filter fix-links-single-file.lua *.md -o outfile.html
```

Comment: this worked for me if the link does not contain any spaces. is there something special when spaces are involved?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to fix the links.

To replace the .md with an .html we use the [gsub](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) command from lua which uses pattern matching and replacement.

The pattern to match against is as follows: `(.+)%.md(.*)`. This provides the option to either have `#Topic` attached or not. For example, if you don't just concatenate, but rather use multiple files.
For single file just don't input the name of the document in the markdown.

The Lua for multiple files looks as follows:

```
-- fix-links-multiple-files.lua
function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('(.+)%.md%(.*)', '%1.html%2')
  return link
end
```

Run it with

```
pandoc --lua-filter fix-links-multiple-files.lua file-1.md -o file-1.html
```

In the case of a single file, as stated above, we can just drop the file part of the link:

```
-- fix-links-single-file.lua
function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('.+%.md%#(.+)', '#%1')
  return link
end
```

Run with

```
pandoc --lua-filter fix-links-single-file.lua *.md -o outfile.html
```

Thank to @tarleb for the answer before, it was really helpful