# Exporting Markdown to HTML While Updating Links

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have two markdown documents; **A.md** and **B.md**. The **A** document includes a link to **B** using the tag `(B)[B.md]`. That link works great when navigating markdown documents.

Now I want to export all my markdown files to HTML as part of a release documentation package. The issue is that in the exported HTML the link points to **B.md** when what I really want it to point to is the newly exported **B.html**.

Anyone have any ideas on how to automatically update links?

I am currently using pandoc to export to html because it has a command line interface and therefore I can script its execution.

Right now my workaround is to update A so that it links to the html version of B, `[B](b.html)`. This allows my html exported documents to work but breaks navigation within the original markdown files. Alternatively I could replace the links myself as part of the script but that sounds painful.

What I am really looking for is a way to export a collection of markdown files as a standalone documentation package.

Comment: A [Pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) should work fine for this. Although, it sounds like what you really want is a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to change the link from `.md` to `.html`:

```
-- file: change-links.lua
function Link (link)
  link.target = link.target:gsub('.md$', '.html')
  return link
end
```

Adding the parameter `--lua-filter=change-links.lua` to your call to pandoc should be all that is needed.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48169995/2425163).

Comment: The solution you outlined directly answered my question. I ended up researching static site generators at the recommendation of @Waylan. I did some test runs with various tools but MkDocs is the best fit. It updates links automatically and fits well into my process of generating software release documentation (not blogs, wordpress content, etc.). I am in the process of transitioning from pandoc to MkDocs. Thanks to both of you.