# Convert markdown via pandoc and with resolving nested .md files

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have three markdown files in folder.
And they are linked like this:

```
test.md
 \__Nest1.md
     \__Nest2.md
```

Link created like this (for example in test.md):

```
![ls](Nest1)
```

And it is look like this:
[image]

So, how I can create single file with pandoc, that will include content from all three files?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Does any of these resources answer your question?
* https://stackoverflow.com/q/48169995/2425163
* https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/include-files

Comment: @tarleb thank you for links! I check out solutions. In my question I mean , that I want get result as in `include-files` solution , but without additional class {.include}. Instead of this class use links in md like `![[nest1.md]]`

Comment: Ok, thanks. You could try to adapt the filter I mentioned [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/553#issuecomment-343327058), or some other solution from that issue.