# pandoc: how to make links work in Markdown across single-PDF PDF output AND Markdown multi-file output?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using a single set of (multiple) Markdown files to produce both (a) single-file PDF output, via pandoc, and (b) multi-web-page WWW output, using markdown directly (with docsify, https://docsify.js.org/#/).

The problem is how to specify a link within my document.

- For pdf, I'd like to use markdown that looks like `[link](#id1)`. Because the PDF is a single-file output, I need to specify an internal link.
- But for md/html, I'd like to use markdown that looks like `[link](otherfile)`.

I am totally willing to handcode these, e.g.:

```c
#if PDF
[link](#id1)
#elsif MD
[link](otherfile)
#endif
```

because they don't occur very often (but I don't know any construct of the above sort within markdown). The main goal is to write the md files once and never change them, even if it takes a little gymnastics within the md files themselves.

I could imagine this could be done with a (custom) pandoc filter, but I can't imagine this isn't a problem someone else has encountered (and solved) before.

Comment: I have a similar set up.
Right now I have two Makefiles.
I first build the html-set.
Than I run the pdf-Makefile which calles a shell script with a bunch of `sed` commands.
 This also helps me to incorporate .svg images in the html-set and pdf-images in the pdf-set.
Its not pretty. But it works. I Would be very curious about a better way.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48172069/2425163): it's about HTML output, but applies to this question as well.